# Acrobat Reader prompt saving pdf file when closing it (created with TCPDF)

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework2, tcpdf

my problem is with the pdf opened in Acrobat Reader, created with TCPDF on ZF2.

The file is created fine (except the size of the file, around 500kb), content is fine, but when trying to close the file, Acrobat prompts for saving the changes, though there is no changes. After saving the file and overwriting, the file size drops to around 40kb. So the file size is reduced over 10 times, but there is no visible change in the contents or otherwise.

Closest I got to any related answer was this thread here http://forums.planetpdf.com/save-file-prompt-when-closing_topic36.html

As I understand the issue is related to "The xref table is malformed", but my experience with pdf is not enough to understand the root of my problem. Sample file is available here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29072870/test_pdf.pdf

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just checked the file you included no changes in size before or after opening file size was 524kb on my machine

Comment: When I changed from WinXP-32bit to Win7-64bit i had the same problem, (Do you want to save changes to before closing) but maybe I added too much code to my TCPDF code, my previous TCPDF files work but not the new ones, hopefully i will find my coding bug.(i use mysqlPHP no Zend)

Answer (score 3):

Only the first 7036 bytes of your file make up your actual pdf. Everything thereafter is some HTML code. Thus, you should check your pdf creation code, it seems to contain some HTML creation code (leftover from copy&paste? Added by the framework?), too.

The Adobe Reader shows these leading 7KB and eventually offers to save them as a repaired file encoded like the Reader prefers it (exploding those 7KB to your 40KB).

PS: I just saw that after the HTML code there additionally are about 80KB of null bytes.

It looks like you received a whole byte buffer 0x80000 (= 524288 decimally) bytes in size containing your PDF, some HTML, and some yet unused space.

Comment: thank you!

the problem was of course between the chair and the keyboard ... and in my inexperience with pdf. i did not exit the process after outputting the pdf, therefor zend continued and inserted that excess data in the end of the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

problem actually not quite solved yet :)

the issue got much more strange now. on chrome everything works perfect, created pdf is solid and no additional data. whereas in firefox the output of the pdf is fine, saving the file works fine, opening the file with acrobat fine, closing produces same result in prompt for saving without any changes made. apparently there is still the portion of null bytes present in the end of the file. when using the "download as file" option in TCPDF output the result is correct, no additional data after EOF. only happens when pdf is output in the browser (firefox) and saved from there. could it be some firefox's issue? can one check the file for this kind of excess data and remove it somehow?

Comment: Maybe you should supply some code. Then people knowing your environment might better help. I only know my way around inside pdfs and, therefore, hardly can help anymore.